# Safari Developer Certificate on Windows 7 not working for me. What should I do?

Tags: windows-7, safari, certificate

I want to create a safari extension on my Windows 7 pc. I have created a safari developer certificate properly but I couldn't really install it. After some googling, I tried importing it into Personal and Trusted Root Certification authorities. But Extension Builder keeps showing "No Safari Developer Certificate." I even revoked the certificate and created a new one. Still no luck. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you enter something like `certmgr.msc` in the run command in Windows, you will get to see something like this:

[image]

So using the certificate consists of the following steps:

1. Save the file and run the command in `cmd.exe` as directed in the developer certificate generator in extension certificate developer.
2. When you are done, check the certmgr (shown in the image above) and see a certificate named "Safari Developer" installed somewhere near Certificate Enrollment Requests. Cut the certificate and paste one copy inside trusted root certification Authorities and another inside Personal.
3. Generate the `csr` file and install the file inside Personal folder and trusted root certification Authorities folder.
4. Extension builder will now recognize the certificate.